# Could the canopy of a Dyson Tree actually work?

Tags: flora, engineering, genetic-engineering, megastructures, asteroids

Piggybacking on Q: What is required to make a Dyson Tree a feasible space habitat?

So I recently came across the concept of the Dyson Tree (I’d already heard of the Dyson Sphere). For those who don’t know it’s a genetically modified tree, or several trees, that grow on a comet or asteroid. One version of it is where the canopy from the trees encapsulates the entire comet in a sphere, and creates an atmosphere within. So you’d have a closed in micro-g habitable environment (please look up what a Dyson Tree is as I am sure I have not done it justice in my description).

But the possibility of such a thing made me curious about one aspect in particular, the canopy. I get that it’s a genetically modified tree, and that level of genetic modification is not possible just yet, so we’re talking future super science. So given that, **could the canopy cover actually work to protect itself and what’s within?**

Potential problems being the solar winds, radiation, lack of sunlight, or too much sunlight, creating an airtight seal to keep air pressure in, and I’m sure many other things I’m not even aware of.

*I did do some research but I couldn’t find anything concrete.*

Comment: It is handwavium, deep in that territory, especially with that form, less so to have a biological component in all that. If to iron some kinck probably not impossible, but hardly practical, basically any other random solution looks better. So it for those who preffer form over substance.

Comment: Perhaps it's a nanotech device that is modeled after a biological tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a huge problem here--holding the pressure.  Large pressure tanks have to be tough.  For something big enough to hold an asteroid, very, very tough.  Trees simply don't have that kind of strength.